# How to access to TFS registry throughout REST API or .NET Core suitable way

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, .net-core

I need to work with TFS items throughout REST API to update current solution, but seems it impossible to work with some features like TFS registry thought REST API and I cannot find fresh SOAP API alternative on this issue.

This TFS REST API documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 not even mention such thing as TFS registry edition. Therefore, I tried to search modern implementation of SOAP API that will works well with .NET Core. For example, I tried to search for documentation on `ITeamFoundationRegistry` interface or *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client* - the library, which provide this SOAP API access. 
I only found pages like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff736976(v=vs.120) with note about outdated information on page. I cannot find any modern tools, which can replace such SOAP API. 
In addition, if I simple try to add this *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client* as nuget package, than I found nothing.

Therefore, I need to found out, is it possible to access TFS Registry via REST API or is there are any solution to work with TFS Registry with .NET Core and if we have such solution, where I can get any modern documentation on this solution.

Comment: I've been working with TFS for a decade and have no idea what you mean by "tfs registry". Can you explain what you're trying to do in more detail?

Comment: May be I am using slightly wrong terminology, but by this I mean some entries, which you read/edit by interface `ITeamFoundationRegistry`. For some reasons I need to use it. However, it turned out, that this _Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client_ lib better works with .NET Framework, so I need switch my project from .NET Core back to .NET Framework.